# How to deal with this kind of map data

Tags: json, dart

```
{productid: 456813, token: 6t90jwawirc3dznbn8khevkg1b6n7vnx, quote_id: 813, specData: {{super_attribute: {218: {value: 297}}, qty: 1}, {super_attribute: {218: {value: 298}}, qty: 1}, {super_attribute: {218: {value: 299}}, qty: 1}, {super_attribute: {218: {value: 300}}, qty: 1}, {super_attribute: {218: {value: 301}}, qty: 1}}}
```

print(jsonEncode(params));

Got the following error

```
Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of '_CompactLinkedHashSet<dynamic>'
```

Comment: You `params` contains a `Set` which cannot be encoded to JSON. More specific, `specData` is a `Set` which should properly be a `List` instead.

Comment: Does the `token` value not contain quotes around it's value as in your example here?

Comment: @daddygames My guess is that his example is just calling `print()` on some data structure. That will output the structure without any quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data structure is not valid for directly converting to JSON. The main problem is that you have a `Set` in `params` (`specData`) which is not allowed for `jsonEncode` which is documented with:

> If value contains objects that are not directly encodable to a JSON string (**a value that is not a number, boolean, string, null, list or a map with string keys**), the `toEncodable` function is used to convert it to an object that must be directly encodable.

There are two solutions here. You can either change `specData` to be a `List`. Or you can use the `toEncodable` argument to `jsonEncode` to change the type of your `Set` to `List` when converting to JSON:

```
  print(jsonEncode(params, toEncodable: (object) {
    if (object is Set) {
      return object.toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception('Could not encode: $object');
    }
  }));
```

**Bonus:** It is difficult to know if your key's in `super_attribute` is `int` or `String`. But you must use `String` if you want to convert to JSON. If it is `int` you can also use the `toEncodable` to fix that but it will get a little messy so it is best if you can get some control over your data structure.